# Rubber Material

Tags: materials

I am working to create a rubber material (not car tire rubber but more like a muted-yellow rubber band rubber). Something similar to this:

[image]

It does not not have to be crazy complicated and realistic, but I've currently just got a *Diffuse BSDF* and a *Glossy BSDF* mixed with a *Layer Weight > Facing* at *.2* to soften it. It works, but I think it can probably be improved upon.

[image]

*My current nodes.*

Comment: Maybe add some Subsurface Scattering and some textures?

Comment: Flat shaders are the clear giveaway for CG, nothing in this world is so homogeneous. Try adding a some texture to the diffuse material, plus some bump to make the material seem porous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An attempt... I used a translucent shader (which seems to be better then SSS). The other nodes are yours.
Concerning the irregularities both Voronoi and Noise could be used.

[image]

Comment: Very nice! And it requires very few samples! After some more toying around, I came up with a more complicated setup that utilizes SSS and may look a tad more realistic, but takes infinitely more samples __and__ CPU to look nice. Thanks much for this very practical, cheap, and realistic solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I came up with. Mostly a combination of all the advise.

[image: Final Render]

[image: Nodes]

Answer (score 3):

I came up later with a more complicated solution that requires more samples, but I thought it was worth posting anyway. Kudos to @lemon, though, for his efficient and realistic design.

*Node Setup:*

[image]

*Final Result:*

[image]

*Brief Explanation:*

The crazy values in the *Mapping* node are specific to the rubber band mesh I created (you will probably need different ones). The *Subsurface Scattering BSSRDF* and *Diffuse BSDF* combined with a *Voronoi > Intensity* fac to create small surface irregularities and give it a translucent feel. The *Glossy BSDF* at 0.1 with the *Layer Weight > Facing* at 0.3 softened the edges and made it more rubbery without making it hard and reflective (this is a very widely known and used method for leather, rubber, and anything soft in general).